# Using SSH From Google Cloud Functions To Outside Server

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create a Google Cloud Function in Python that allows me to SSH into my 3rd party webserver on Rackspace and do a MySQL query. I can do it from my home environment, but I can not figure out how to make the SSH connection to my server from Google Cloud Functions. Here is the code I'm using from home:

```
import pymysql
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser('~')

sql_hostname = 'localhost'
sql_username = '[my-username]'
sql_password = '[my-password]'
sql_main_database = '[my-database]'
sql_port = 3306
ssh_host = 'my-website.com'
ssh_user = '[my-username]'
ssh_password = '[my-password]'
ssh_port = 22
sql_ip = '1.1.1.1.1'

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_password=ssh_password,
        #ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
            passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
    query = '''SELECT * from my_table limit 10;'''
    data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()
print(data)
```

What do I have to do to make an SSH connection to my webserver from Google Cloud Functions?

Comment: Do you have billing enabled for your function? Functions can't make external requests until billing is enabled.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your debugging details.  What exactly isn't working the way you expect?  Is there an error message?  What's actually happening?

Comment: Please add what error message you are getting and, as mentioned by dustin, have you enabled billing?